# Terraform cidrsubnets

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Seeking to get some help around the cidrsubents functionality in terraform. I have a vpc cidr, 10.0.0.0/16, I wanted to get three private database subnets /25, four public /26 subnets and four other private /23 subnets. How can I achieve this dynamically using cidrsubnets? Also, in future if I need to add an extra database subnet, it should be scalable such that it doesn’t re create any other subnets. Any help would be appreciated. TIA!